# Question about using L'Hopital rule in a limit

Tags: calculus

Consider the function
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 & x\geq 0\\
\cos x & x<0
\end{cases}
$$ 
Note that $f$ is differentiable for all $x\neq 0$ and that
$$
f'(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x & x>0\\
-\sin x & x<0
\end{cases}
$$
so $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=0$. Now let 
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{f(x)}{x} & x\neq0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
On the one hand $g$ is not continues on $0$ since 
$$
\lim_{x\to0^{+}}g(x)=0\qquad
\lim_{x\to0^{-}}g(x)=-\infty
$$
But on the other hand by L'Hôpital's rule
$$
\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=
\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=0=g(0)
$$
Where is the error? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)\neq\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$$
but
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}g(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{-}}\frac{f(x)}{x}.$$
Second of all you may only use l'Hôpital's rule if $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{-}}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{-}}x=0$$ or $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{-}}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{-}}x=\infty.$$ As $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{-}}f(x)=1\neq0=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{-}}x$$
you cannot use l'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Also $f$ is not differentiable as it is not continuous.

Comment: why $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)\neq\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ ?

Comment: For one thing $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}g(x)$ does not exist, so you can't really equate it to another limit.